# TagManager in Android : Failed to load the container. NO default container resource found with resource ID -1

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-tag-manager

I followed every step right in setting up tag manager + firebase:

FirebaseB, GA and Tag Manager properly set up
Install necessary nugets as stated above.
Put the JSON of the tag manager container inside assets/containers
When I tested in iOS, it went smoothly, however in Android, I kept getting this error:

Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled

I also encounter this in the device log afterwards:

Failed to load the container. NO default container resource found with resource ID -1

refresh test, containerHolder: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.dc@XXXXXXX

Steps to Reproduce:

1) Create a Xamarin Forms app.
2) In the Android project, install the necessary nuget packages.
3) Enable firebase and call _firebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);.
4) Log some events
5) Create a GA and google tag manager account. Create a container (Android), then download the JSON file. Put the JSON file inside Assets/containers folder.
6) Run the application while Device logcat is running (you can check error here)

These are the packages that I used:

PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics" Version="71.1608.1" 
    PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version="71.1610.1 
 PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.TagManager" Version="71.1604.1 
 PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics" Version="71.1630.1 
 PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="71.1740.1

Has anyone encountered this and knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

Using Tag Manager in Xamarin Android , after installing Nuget Package for solution . There are follow steps for reference :

- 1, Create a Google Analytics account, please make sure you select a mobile account (Under New Property - you'll have to select mobile/Web).
- 2,Create a Google Tag Manager account - create a container, then create a tag of type Google Analytics - universal analytics. a) Put your analytics account id in the Tracking ID (should be in the form "UA-XXXXXX-X"). b) Create a macro for screen name (you can view in the screenshots 'TagManagerMacro.jpeg') c) The Rule Track Type should be App View. d) In the more settings --> basic configuration --> screen name - add the macro we defined in step b. e) In Firing rules - make sure your rule is set for always.

In your Activity, call to

```
var tagmanager = TagManagerClass.GetInstance(this);

 var pendingResult = _tagmanager.LoadContainerPreferNonDefault("GTM-XXXXXX",
            Resource.Raw.gtm_analytics);

pendingResult.SetResultCallback(new TagMnagerResultCallback(), 2, TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

After the callback as returned, you can fire events like this:

```
_tagmanager.DataLayer.PushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.MapOf("screenName", "testScreen"));
```

This guide was followed by the guidelines instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/).

Comment: Hi Sir! Thanks for replying to this question of mine. I'm just curious is this step still necessary even for Android 5 and up? Also, I'd like to have firebase as my data layer.. would this also suffice?

Comment: @Angelo Okey , if need to have firebase ,will not sure also works . If have good idea will update here .